# Nucleon Database Master - #FileInclude (C#/LINQ)

Tags: c#, nucleon

I am using Nucleon Database Master, which so far has been great for managing my mongodb servers.  However, there are a few examples where they show the LINQ Query editor in use with your own data types and classes, but I can't find any documentation anywhere on how to do it.

There are hints in the comments in the c# query it generates:

```
//Linq to MongoDB Help:http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+LINQ+Tutorial
//The following sample shows a LINQ to MongoDB query. Use #FileInclude command to add your entity class for LINQ Query.
//var collection = this.db.GetCollection<Employee>("Employees"); 
//var result = from emp in collection.AsQueryable<Employee>()
//where emp.FirstName == "Andrew"
//select emp;
//Output(result);
```

Everything in the editor works great, apart from I have no idea how to "Use #FileInclude command to add your entity class LINQ Query".

I'm sure it's possible as they have screenshots demonstrating it on their website (I have emailed them, but haven't got a response).

http://www.nucleonsoftware.com/images/dm/LinqToEF_Select1.png

So, anyone either know how to do this, or otherwise have an idea what the #FileInclude thing might be about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have had a response back from Nucleon Software, and thought I'd share it here for anyone else with the same question:

You need to add a comment at the top of the query editor, e.g.:

```
//#FileInclude C:\myFile.cs 
using System;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
....
```

However, they apparently will soon be adding a feature to add you custom DLL's to the LINQ query.